# Django. Console error 404 wpad.dat windows

Tags: python-3.x, django

Django console:
Not Found: /wpad.dat [23/Jun/2023 12:31:18] "GET /wpad.dat HTTP/1.1" 404 2537.
This error is sent to the console every 10 seconds

I have not found any information on this error
how to remove/fix this error